# Tkinter : avoid new titlebar by using toplevel

Tags: tkinter, attributes, titlebar, toplevel

I use in this program different toplevels over my main window (2 exactly). I use the attributes "alpha" to make a buzzy effect when a window appears under a new one, it's easier to read the new window.
With the toplevel, it's cool because even when I have my 2 toplevels open, on the windows bar (where there are all the list of my applications open), it displays only the titlebar of the main window of my program (I hope it's clear^^, see pictures).
But when I destroy the second toplevel and I come back to the first one, I have an other titlebar which appears in the windows bar, in link to the fisrt toplevel.
It appears only when I use the attributes to come back at "alpha"=1 to my first toplevel, when I destroy the second toplevel. Indeed when I don't use the attributes, even when I destroy the second toplevel I still have only one titlebar in link to the main window.

Why is there this behavior with the function attributes, and how to avoid it ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKfW2.png)[image]

Code of my program :

...

```
from tkinter import *

def toplevel_1():
    global top_1
    fenetre.attributes("-alpha",0.25)
    top_1=Toplevel(fenetre)
    top_1.overrideredirect(1)
    top_1.grab_set()
    top_1["bg"]="black"
    button_toplevel_2=Button(top_1,text="Open TopLevel 2",command=toplevel_2)
    button_toplevel_2.pack()
    label_toplevel_1=Label(top_1,text="TopLevel 1",bg="black",fg="red",font=50)
    label_toplevel_1.pack()
    button_destroy_top_1=Button(top_1,text="Destroy TopLevel 1",command=destroy_top_1)
    button_destroy_top_1.pack()
    top_1.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d"%(500,500,250,250))
def destroy_top_1():
    top_1.destroy()
    fenetre.attributes("-alpha",1)

def toplevel_2():
    global top_2
    top_1.attributes("-alpha",0.5)
    top_2=Toplevel(top_1)
    top_2.overrideredirect(1)
    top_2.grab_set()
    top_2["bg"]="blue"
    label_toplevel_2=Label(top_2,text="TopLevel 2",bg="blue",fg="green",font=50)
    label_toplevel_2.pack()
    button_destroy_top_2=Button(top_2,text="Destroy TopLevel 2",command=destroy_top_2)
    button_destroy_top_2.pack()
    top_2.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d"%(250,250,500,500))
def destroy_top_2():
    top_2.destroy()
    top_1.attributes("-alpha",1)
    top_1.grab_set()

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.title("Les Chevaliers d'Arthur")
menu=Menu(fenetre)
menu.add_command(label="Quitter",command=fenetre.destroy)
fenetre.config(menu=menu)
fenetre.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d"%(1000,750,100,100))

button_toplevel_1=Button(fenetre,text="Open TopLevel 1",command=toplevel_1)
button_toplevel_1.pack()

fenetre.mainloop()
```

...

Thank you for the help !!!!!!

Comment: If you remove `.overrideredirect(1)`,it will show you the title bar.

Comment: Ok I found the solution, I used "top_1.attributes("-toolwindow",1)", it avoid to the toplevel to appear in the title bar.